# InvalidRequestError during concurrent requests with FastAPI, aiosqlite, and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, aiosqlite

I am encountering an issue with a FastAPI application using aiosqlite and SQLAlchemy when subjected to a high number of concurrent requests, specifically during a penetration test with 100 parallel queries using Locust. The application works well with a few parallel requests, but approximately 20% of the queries fail under heavy load.

```py
import uuid
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, AsyncEngine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import SingletonThreadPool
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class testdb(Base):
    __tablename__ = "testdb"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    data = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False)


async_engine:AsyncEngine = create_async_engine("sqlite+aiosqlite:///./test.db", echo=True, future=True, poolclass=SingletonThreadPool)


async def getsession() -> AsyncSession:
    async_session = sessionmaker(bind=async_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
    async with async_session() as newsession:
        yield newsession

app = FastAPI()
lock = asyncio.Lock()

@app.post('/save')
async def save(session:AsyncSession=Depends(getsession)):
    new = testdb(data=uuid.uuid4().hex)
    session.add(new)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(new)
    return new

@app.on_event('startup')
async def onstartup():
    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
```

Details:

- The issue occurs during the execution of the **`/save`** endpoint, specifically when calling **`await session.refresh(new)`** after committing the session.
- I am using an **`AsyncSession`** and an **`AsyncEngine`** with a **`SingletonThreadPool`** for database connections.

The error traceback I receive is as follows:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 419, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 758, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 778, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 299, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 79, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 74, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 299, in app
    raise e
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 294, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 191, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/test_sqlalchemy.py", line 34, in save
    await session.refresh(new)
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 327, in refresh
    await greenlet_spawn(
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 202, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.switch(value)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxx/testdb.nosync/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3140, in refresh
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not refresh instance '<testdb at 0x108ed9410>'
```

How to fix this behavior?

I conducted a penetration test on the /save endpoint using Locust with 100 parallel user sessions and anticipated a seamless execution without any tracebacks. The module versions used for the test are as follows:

- uvicorn[standard]==0.27.0

- fastapi==0.109.2

- aiosqlite==0.19.0

- sqlalchemy[asyncio]==2.0.25

Python Version 3.11

Despite these efforts, I encountered the same error consistently. I also experimented with a version utilizing SQLModel, as well as various combinations of older versions of FastAPI and SQLAlchemy, all resulting in the persistence of the issue.

I tested with Linux Ubuntu 22.04. and Mac OS on a MacBook Air M2.

Comment: Are you going to use `aiosqlite` in production or you just want to test it? `aiosqlite` is not a good choice for high-load systems.

Comment: No, but the issue here is that simultaneous accesses to the database have a chance to raise a traceback. I use FastAPI and some other tools with asyncio, and I want all the code to be within the async context.

The pentest only shows the potential for errors. This also occurs with lower load happening at the same time randomly.

Comment: Why do you use `poolclass=SingletonThreadPool`? All async functions run in one thread, and with that class all of them will have one common session. Am I wrong?

Comment: I need to use `poolclass=SingletonThreadPool` or `poolclass=StaticPool` to ensure that only one connection to the database is made. Otherwise, the database may throw a `database locked` exception.

Comment: I think you are wrong here.. Python interpreter will switch between async tasks and if all of them work with the same session it will cause errors. Try using `QueuePool` with `max_overflow=-1`

Answer (score 0):

By including `connect_args={'timeout': 120}` in the `create_async_engine()` function, the database successfully manages the penetration test without encountering any errors. No RequestError or locked Database Error occurs.

On a MacBook Air M2, performing simultaneous writes by 100 users to the database yields 500 Requests/s, as tested with Locust.

```py
import uuid
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, AsyncEngine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import QueuePool
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class testdb(Base):
    __tablename__ = "testdb"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    data = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False)


async_engine:AsyncEngine = create_async_engine("sqlite+aiosqlite:///./test.db", poolclass=QueuePool, max_overflow=-1 ,connect_args={'timeout': 120})


async def getsession() -> AsyncSession:
    async_session = sessionmaker(bind=async_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
    async with async_session() as newsession:
        yield newsession

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/save')
async def save(session:AsyncSession=Depends(getsession)):
    new = testdb(data=uuid.uuid4().hex)
    session.add(new)
    await session.commit()
    await session.refresh(new)
    return new

@app.on_event('startup')
async def onstartup():
    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
```